# How to remove formatting of XDocument in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml

I want to remove the formatting of my xml file after loading into an XDocument. I am having the following code.

```
Dim xmldoc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(XMLStr)
.
.
.
.
Dim FinalStr as String = xmldoc.ToString()
```

when i taking this string i am getting the multiple new lines and multiple spaces. I dont want those spaces and new lines can any one tell me how to remove that.
I know there is an option of `SaveOptions.DisableFormatting` to remove the format, but i am not going to save the document.

And i tried in Regex also but some of the content spaces also removed, so i want to remove ony the formatting spaces and newline which XDocument puts.

**Update:**

I tried `xmldoc.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting)` but its removing some spaces also. For example, when my xml like this

```
<title>My <b>tilte</b> <i>Company</i></title>
```

it removes the space between the `<b>tilte</b> <i>Company</i>` tags.
I want my title as

"My **tilte** *Company*" but it gives "My **tilte***Company*"

Can any one help me.

Comment: What's the entire sample xml look like?  Are you escaping the html?  e.g., it should look like this: `<myXmlElement>&lt;title&gt;My &lt;b&gt;tilte&lt;/b&gt;&lt;i&gt;Company&lt;/i&gt;&lt;/title&gt;</myXmlElement>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I think your problem would be solved using:**

```
Dim xmldoc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(XMLStr, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace)
```

**For more information visit [XDocument.Parse Method (String, LoadOptions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb551294.aspx#Y0)**

Answer (score 11):

You're looking for  `xmldoc.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting)`.

Comment: But there is a problem, when my xml like this "<title>My <b>tilte</b> <i>Company</i></title>" it removes the space between the <b> and <i> tags.